What prevents my house from being recognized as valid housing?
In Terraria, where my cursor is, for some reason it says "This is not valid housing," which I do not understand as it has a light source, a table, and the proper room size. I checked the walls, and they are indeed there (behind the chests included too), and no blocks such as crimson or corruption are interfering with it.

What is wrong with the room?

If a house has a entrance along the vertical axis, it needs to be a 3-block-tall entrance, usually a door. The vertical path doesn't have 3 blocks separating the rooms, but instead a 2-block-tall set of platforms.
https://forums.terraria.org/index.php?threads/why-is-this-house-invalid.50454/#post-1120028

The difference between the left and right rooms appears to be in the number of chests on the floor and the statue in the right one. I've previously seen mentioned that there needed to be a certain amount of empty floor space, which may be taken up by the chests and not by the statue. I would suggest removing a chest or two from the floor of the left side room and seeing if it changes anything.
